# Hibernate: use OneToMany without actually using any primary/foreign key relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have seen hundreds of posts, which is not similar to mine :(

Pls consider the following case.

Mysql Schema:

```
create table parent(
id int,
col1 int,
col2 int,
primary key(id)
)

create table child(
id int,
col1 int,
col2 int,
primary key(id)
)
```

Note that there is no explicit/key relationship between parent & child tables.

Now, all I want is to fetch all the 'child' objects which has same values of  'col1' & 'col2' along while fetching 'parent' [Unidirectional mapping is enough].

Sort of Hibernate entities that I tried,

> ```
> @Entity
> public class parent{
>
> @Id
> private int id;
>
> @Column
> private int col1;
>
> @Column
> private int col2;
>
> @OneToMany
> @JoinColumns({
>     @JoinColumn(name = "col1"),
>     @JoinColumn(name = "col2")
> })
> private List<Child> children;
>
> /**
> Other logic goes here..
> **/
>
> }
> ```

And the Child entity as,

> ```
> @Entity
> public class Child{
>
> @Id
> private int id;
>
> @Column
> private int col1;
>
> @Column
> private int col2;
>
> /**
> Other logic goes here..
> **/
> }
> ```

Result:
Hibernate error reporting that "A Foreign key refering 'Child' from 'Parent' has the wrong number of column. should be 1"

I interpret this expects as, @JoinColumn has to be done only using "id"

Questions:

1) Does all @OneToMany @ManyToOne etc of hibernate requires, explicit/key references between the tables/at the entities [annotated by @Id]?

2) What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: 1. no. 2. by specifying the referencedColumnName in JoinColumn, and removing the col1 and col2 fields, that are redundant. But I would really, really fix the schema instead and use proper keys. Or simply use an ad-hoc HQL query when trying to find the "children" of a parent entity by col1 and col2.

Comment: Yes, ad-hoc HQL query was the only working solution I have now. Adding referencedColumName throws error like "referencedColumnNames(col1, col2) of child referencing  parent not mapped to a single property".

Comment: You should not use in relation, like ManyToOne or any other, not id fields. Entities should be related only by id (doesn't matter, single field id or composite id). So in this case using of separate HQL, as suggested @JBNizet, will be best way.

Comment: Oops :( anyways, this answers my two days hell of search!! Is there any offical docs? References to readout more?

Answer (score 0):

Here TableA has OneToMany relationship with TableB i.e., one record in TableA can have multiple records in TableB. Since col1 in TableA is referenced as Foreign key in col1 of TableB. The below JPA code successfully fetch all the results.

```
DROP table x.TableA;
CREATE TABLE x.TableA (
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    col1 varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_col1 PRIMARY KEY(col1) 
);

DROP table x.TableB;
CREATE TABLE x.TableB ( 
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)NOT NULL,
    col1 varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    col2 varchar(10) NULL
);

ALTER TABLE x.TableB
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TableB_col1 FOREIGN KEY (col1)
      REFERENCES x.TableA (col1)
;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA", schema = "x")
public class ClassA implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "col1")
  private String col1;


  @OneToMany(
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
      orphanRemoval = true,
      fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "col1", referencedColumnName = "col1")
  private List<ClassB> objB = new ArrayList<>();
}

----------------------------------


@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB", schema = "x")
public class ClassB implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "col1")
  private String col1;

  @Column(name = "col2")
  private String col2;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with:
  `@OneToMany
      @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name = "col1", referencedColumnName="col1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "col2", referencedColumnName="col2")
    })`

Comment: Pls check my comment, this doesn't help

Comment: Please add some explanation along with the code and also put the code in proper format.